# Плавно скрывающийся текст при переполнении блока CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

пытаюсь сделать вот такой элемент [image: ЖЕЛАЕМЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ CSS]

чтобы текст который выходит за блок по ширине красиво скрывался белой внутренней тенью.
Но у меня получается нечто совершенно иное, буквы сжимаются и залазят друг на друга, тень нормальная не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста решение этой задачки, или где его можно подсмотреть

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой вариант с `:after` (или с `:before`, эффект будет тот же) вполне себе решает задачу

```css
.text {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #334d74;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0, #fff 100%);
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Какой-то очень большой текст, который не влезет в блок</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот код работает, хотя в разы проще того что я наворотил)